# Wait for Service to Start/Stop

Tags: c++, windows-services

I am using the service controller in C++ to manage a windows service.

I can use the `StartService( )` and `ControlService( )` functions to start and stop the service.

However, is there a standard way to wait for the service to actually start and stop?

I could obviously loop calling `QueryServiceStatusEx( )` and wait until the status is `Running` or `Stopped` respectively.

Is there a neater way of achieving the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have control over this other service?

Comment: Yes, I can start the service and stop it. But I need a way to wait until the service has stopped so that I can edit a configuration file before starting it again.

Comment: What i mean is do you have access to its source code. If thats the case you could create an event and wait for that.

Comment: Ah, no sorry, it's a 3rd party Service. But wouldn't that event only exist within the service? Or is it possible to have globally accessible events?

Comment: You can create Global events also. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. However, as mentioned it's a 3rd party service so I'm not able to do that.

Comment: I've always done it using polling. You could use `NotifyServiceStatusChange`, but that looks pretty nasty.

Comment: @Alan: Yeah that's what I'm going to implement. I had a look at NotifyServiceStatusChange and it does indeed look nasty!

Answer (score 1):

Afaik Service start and stop create windows event log events. Maybe you could install a handler for those and wait for the event from your application. If your application is also a service mark it as depending on the 3rd party service then you should not have to wait on it.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can do this using [ServiceController.WaitForStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.waitforstatus.aspx).  You could do it this way (one line of code) and wrap the C# within your C++ code.

Otherwise, you will likely be futzing around with WMI ([Win32_Service class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) or the Event Log.